# Как улучшить распознование речи используя speech_recognition Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Вопрос в заголовке.
Желательно привести пример кода.

Comment: Читай документацию, говори чётче или пиши свою библиотеку/реализацию распознования речи

Comment: Ничего лучше особо нет (для питона). Так что никак...

Comment: Что значит "улучшить распознование речи"? Приведите используемые метрики, ваш пайплайн обучения, хоть что-нибудь...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica а для других языков есть что-нибудь получше?

Comment: Точно не знаю, я питонист. Но вроде у с# неплохо... (винда).

Comment: @dIm0n Что вы докапываетесь? Вы сами хоть это библиотеку пробовали? Я пробовал и знаю, что если говорить не по слогам, то она работает... _terribly_ **[ВЫРЕЗАНО ЦЕНЗУРОЙ]** ... да и по слогам тоже.

Comment: `wit.ai`.......

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica я пытаюсь дать удочку, а не рыбку :)